# Trying to use function arguments as default arguments in one function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am currently working on a recursive binary search algorithm. The details are not important, but I am trying to use a function parameter as the default value to another parameter:

`def binary_search(items_list: List[int], item: int, lower = 0, upper = len(items_list)) -> bool:`

In this function, if it is called without lower and upper bounds, it should just have the length of the list as the upper bound. Further on, however, I want to call this function recursively, and have its upper and lower bound defined by the binary search algorithm. My IDE says that items_list is an undefined name. Is there any way to use a (modification of a) function argument as a default value in the same function?

The full (faulty) code is:

```
from typing import List

def binary_search(items_list: List[int], item: int, lower = 0, upper = len(items_list)) -> bool:
    middle = (lower+upper)//2
    
    if len(lower-upper) == 0: return False
    if items_list[middle] == item: return True
    
    if item < items_list[middle]:
        return binary_search(items_list, item, lower, middle - 1)
    else:
        return binary_search(items_list, item, middle + 1, upper)
```

I have no idea how to fix this, and in trying to look it up, I only get *what* default functional arguments are. I hope someone with more python knowledge can help me.

Comment: The usual way is to use default value `upper=None` and then add `if upper is None: upper = len(items_list)` at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since keyword arguments are not "aware" of other arguments, as you have experienced, you need to off-load this into the function itself. One option could be like this:

```
def binary_search(items_list: List[int], item: int, lower = 0, upper = None) -> bool:
    if upper is None:
        upper = len(items_list)
    ...
```